# How to get Twilio conference participants after it is over?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

As per Twilio [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list-get-filters) `curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Conferences/CFbbe4632a3c49700934481addd5ce1659/Participants.json -u 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token'` should give list of participants but I don't get list of participants after conference is over, I only get data back when conference is `in-progress`. Whereas if I go to Twilio console, I am able to see all the participants details(timestamp, phone numbers, duration etc) in conference logs section.

Is there a way I can get all the participant information through APIs after conference is `completed`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Participants list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant#list) really refers to the current participants of a conference, so that you can manipulate the current participants (by muting or ejecting them from the conference for example).

If you want to store a list of all the participants over the course of the conference then I recommend you use the [statusCallback` to receive webhooks for each participant joining the conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallback) and store the details in your application.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That's good idea but I am worried about the difference in data of Twilio and my store because of latency and asynchronous nature of events, but on the other hand if I capture those events I'll get to collect more useful data and process it in near real time. I will go ahead with your idea for now but I am wondering if Twilio has all the data of conference and its participants to show on console, why don't they expose it as API?

Comment: Good question, I will ask internally.

Comment: Thanks @philnash let us know if they plan to have this API in upcoming releases

Comment: I'm afraid there is no plan to include these details in the API in the near future. Catching the webhook events is the best way to do this now.

Comment: No, a participant in the API refers to an active participant in a conference.