# How to build administrative functions in Twilio Programmable Voice (Conference)

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm playing around Twilio programmable Voice (Conference) along with PHP.

I'm unable to implement administrative functions like muting/un-muting all participants, start & stop recording etc by moderator of the conference, I preferably would like to use *1, *2, *3, *4 as keypad presses by moderator to have control over the active ongoing conference call.

Appreciate your feedback.

The flow I've created so far as prototype is working good.

- Participant/moderator dials Twilio number
- TwiML greets users by  and prompts to capture PIN code by using
- PIN code validated by  action URL on my server
- When two participant & moderator joins conference is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to achieve this, you need to add a couple of things to your conference.

First, add the [`hangupOnStar` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar) to the `<Dial>` for your moderator. That will allow the moderator to temporarily leave the conference by dialling `*`.

When they do, Twilio will request the URL in the `action` attribute. You will want to respond to that request with TwiML that allows the moderator to perform the muting action, so you'll need a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). The `<Gather>` will need an `action` attribute that receives the `Digits` pressed by the moderator, performs the action (muting/unmuting) using the REST API and returns TwiML to put the moderator back into the `<Conference>`.

Does that help?

Comment: I'm slowly getting there, but I can't wait to thank you for the help and pointing me in right direction.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. Hope the rest of the application goes well!

Comment: Hi @philnash, one more clarification.

I reached performing action muting/unmuting participant during active conference using the REST API.

$participant = $twilio->conferences("CFb...")->participants("CA4...")->update(array("muted" => True));

I realized I can only mute/unmute single participant by using CallSid (CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX).

I also assume from your earlier answer (link below) that I have to keep record of all CallSid in my app using statusCallback` to receive webhooks for each participant joining the conference. Kindly confirm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481929

Comment: In order to keep all the CallSids that were part of the conference, then yes, I recommend you store them when you receive the webhook. If you just need to enumerate the participants during the conference, you can use the [participants resource to list the current participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant).