# Twilio - How can I set a moderator in a Conference?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working on my first Twilio project.

**The target:**

Using just phones (without any kind of UI for agents), I would like to perform this flow into a conference:

1. Customer calls and (after a selection menu) a conference is started.
2. Agent1 joins the conference and chats with Customer to get some basic info (Agent1 is called by Twilio; it is an outbound call).
3. Agent1 makes *something* to join Agent2 to the conference.
4. A 3-party conference is performed (customer, agent1 and agent2).

**The issue:**

Remind that I am not using any UI and, AFAIK, DTMF doesn't work into a conference. So, in order to get an input from conference, I am trying to use *hangupOnStar* as I read in multiple answers here in SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619690/how-to-build-administrative-functions-in-twilio-programmable-voice-conference)).

However, it works just for the initial caller (which seems to be the moderator by default), not for Agent1. I want Agent1 to moderate the conference, just to be able to join Agent2 (probably another outbound call) to the conference.

**The question**

Is it possible to set Agent1 as moderator into this conference? How?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution! I share it below. I hope this to be helpful for somebody... It's not that intuitive, but it works. I followed these steps:

1. Create a CONFERENCE and join Customer (set *startConferenceOnEnter* and *EndConferenceOnExit* to *false*).
2. Create a CALL and hook it to a URL. In that webhook create a TwiML to join Agent1 to conference, allowing *hangupOnStar* to later join Agent2 (in another webhook), and setting *endConferenceOnExit* to *false*, to avoid hanging up Customer's call.
3. Create another webhook to re-join Agent1 after clicking star (*) and let Agent2 join the conference.

I am using Python with Flask framework. Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/start_conference.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def start_conference():
    agent1 = '+XXXXXXXXXXX' # Agent1's phone number
    agent2 = '+XXXXXXXXXXX' # Agent2's phone number
    confName = 'YourConferenceName'

    resp = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()

    # Create a conference and join Customer
    dial.conference(
        confName,
        start_conference_on_enter=False,
        end_conference_on_exit=False,
        max_participants = 3 # Limits participants to 3
    )

    # Call to Agent1 and setup a webhook for this call with a TwiML 
to join to the conference as Moderator
    client.calls.create(
        from_=twilioPhoneNumber,
        to=agent1,
        url=ROOT_URL+'agent1_to_conference.html' # ROOT_URL is the url where app is being executed
    )
    resp.append(dial)

    return str(resp)


@app.route('/agent1_to_conference.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def agent1_to_conference():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    # Join Agent1 to the conference, allowing hangupOnStar 
functionality to join Agent2 later
    dial = Dial(
        action='join_agent2.html',
        method='POST',
        hangup_on_star=True,
    )
    dial.conference(
        confName,
        start_conference_on_enter=True,
        end_conference_on_exit=False # False, to avoid hanging up to Customer
    )
    resp.append(dial)
    return str(resp)


@app.route('/join_agent2.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def join_agent2():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()

    # Re-join Agent1 (after clicking *)
    dial.conference(
        confName,
        start_conference_on_enter=True,
        end_conference_on_exit=True
    )
    resp.append(dial)

    # Join Agent2
    client.conferences(confName).participants.create(
        from_=twilioPhoneNumber,
        to=agent2
    )

    return str(resp)
```